# show "object" and "filter" of stars data without duplicating the "object"

Tags: python, list, readfile, readlines

I want to show "object" & "filter" of stars data without duplicating the "object" because it will be hard to read data line by line.

here is my data:

```
Object    HJD 24...     Filter  Magnitude
SU_Hor    55896.30476      B      14.877
SU_Hor    55896.27438     Ic      13.885
SU_Hor    55896.27349      B      14.809
SU_Hor    55896.27397      V      14.434
SU_Hor    55896.40882     Ic      14.033
SU_Hor    55896.40829      V      14.540
SU_Hor    55896.40770      B      14.941
SU_Hor    55896.34973     Ic      13.958
SU_Hor    55896.34943      V      14.494
SU_Hor    55896.34906      B      14.861
SU_Hor    55896.30542     Ic      13.912
SU_Hor    55896.30512      v      14.440
SU_Hor    55897.38547      V      14.536
SU_Hor    55897.28281      B      14.882
SU_Hor    55897.28317      V      14.428
SU_Hor    55897.28347     Ic      13.927
RZ_Lyr    27359.3030       V      10.630
RZ_Lyr    27684.4510       V      10.610
RZ_Lyr    27685.4780       V      10.580
RZ_Lyr    27701.3150       V      10.700
RZ Lyr    27934.4560       V      10.660
RZ Lyr    27955.4100       V      10.570
rzlyr     30604.2000       V      11.030
RZ_Lyr    55314.5695       B      12.047
RZ_Lyr    55314.5724       B      12.036
RZ_Lyr    55314.5900       B      12.042
RZ_Lyr    55314.6105       B      12.045
RZ_Lyr    55314.6163       B      12.027
RZ_Lyr    55342.3509       B      12.057
RZLyr     55342.3557       B      12.058
RZ_Lyr    55342.3606       B      12.052
RZ_Lyr    55342.3654       B      12.058
```

this is my code so far:

```
# show the name of the Object

f = open("C:/Users/Acer/PycharmProjects/task2_data.txt", "r")
print(f.readlines())

var = f.loc[:, ["Object", "Filter"]]
print(var)
f['Object'].to_frame().head()

f.close()
```

**And this is my error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer\PycharmProjects\readlines\main.py", line 6, in <module>
    var = f.loc[:, ["Object", "Filter"]]
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'loc'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The error is clear, `f` is not a `DataFrame`, therefore has no attribute loc

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use part of the Pandas API, the `.loc[ ]` without having imported pandas.

Comment: This means that your variable "f" has no function loc because it is of type TextIOWrapper. I think loc is for pandas dataframe

Comment: you can use this `pd.read_csv('your_text_file.txt', sep=" ", header=None)` with pd for `import pandas as pd`

Comment: `f.readlines()` does what it says...reads LINES to a list of lines, not a pandas datafram, so you cannot expect it to have the `loc` method, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the file, you can use `pd.read_csv` function with custom separator:

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the file using pd.read_csv (adjust the sep= accordingly)
df = pd.read_csv("your_file.txt", sep=r"\s{2,}", engine="python")

df = df.drop_duplicates("Object")[["Object", "Filter"]]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Object Filter
0   SU_Hor      B
16  RZ_Lyr      V
20  RZ Lyr      V
22   rzlyr      V
29   RZLyr      B
```